# Angular2: get single argument passed in EventEmitter

Tags: angular, eventemitter, angular2-forms

I have 2 components, a 'create' component and child 'form' component. I need the form component to pass the submit event along with the form data.

The real problem is when I log the received event, I get 2, instead of one event/arg. This is what it logs: `Event {isTrusted: true}` and then `Contact {name: inputName}`

How do I filter the events so I only act when I receive the Contact object?

Parent 'create' component:

```
import {Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import {Contact} from './contact';
import {ContactFormComponent} from './contact-form.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'contact-create',
    template: `
      <h2>Nuevo contacto</h2>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">

          <contact-form [contact]="contact" (formSubmitted)="saveContact($event)"></contact-form>

        </div>
      </div>
    `,
    directives: [ContactFormComponent]
})
export class ContactCreateComponent {

  contact: Contact = new Contact('');

  constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private contactService: ContactService) { }

  saveContact(args) {
    console.log(args);
  }
}
```

Child 'form' component

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
import {Contact}   from './contact';

@Component({
  selector: 'contact-form',
  inputs: ['contact'],
  outputs: ['formSubmitted'],
  templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contact-form.component.html',
})
export class ContactFormComponent {

  contact: Contact;
  formSubmitted: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onSubmit(contact) { this.formSubmitted.next(contact); }
}
```

Comment: It would be simpler and cleaner if you rename your output to not match the default [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/submit) ;)

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. Your problem is because your output was matching the default submit event, that's why it was triggering twice. By renaming your output (as you already did in your question) you shouldn't have the problem anymore.

Comment: That's what was actually happening! Thanks @EricMartinez

Comment: You're welcome! Just for your information there's already an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4059) tracking this behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For reference and to add more information note that in the question the Output name initially was `submit` matching the [DOM submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/submit) (OP renamed it in the question because of my lack of explaining the issue in my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559245/angular2-get-single-argument-passed-in-eventemitter/35562175#comment58807703_35559245)) so the original problem is that the component was catching both events : The output defined by OP and the event from the form.

There's an issue (see [#4059](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4059)) tracking this behavior. This clearly should not happen.

The real solution, with all due respect to @Sasxa, is to rename the output to not match the DOM submit event until the issue referenced above is implemented.

Comment: You are right, I focused on the log outputs, didn't even register event names (;

Comment: I am bitten by this too. Keeping output event name to be "submit" was catching twice. almost going to pull my hair. Thanks @Eri Martinez and Mathius for raising on SO. +1